# Converted long to time off by 1 minute

Tags: java, android, time, sharedpreferences, simpledateformat

I have a portion of code that finds a saved time in milliseconds that has been saved by a user previously. When the time is taken from memory then converted to a Simple Date Format for some reason the time gains 1 minute. I can't figure out why this would occur though. Following is the code for retrieving the time and converting it

```
time = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getFloat(String.valueOf(id)+"TIME", 0);
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(new Date((long) time));
            mPickedTimeText.setText(dateString);
```

and the portion of code where the time is saved

```
    this.time = time.getTimeInMillis();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    Editor editor=prefs.edit();
    editor.putFloat(String.valueOf(id)+"TIME", time);
    editor.commit();
    finish();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `float` datatype doesn't have enough precision to represent time to the accuracy of one minute. Store the time as `long` instead.

```
editor.putLong(String.valueOf(id)+"TIME", time);

time = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getLong(String.valueOf(id)+"TIME", 0);
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(new Date(time));
```